# How to write files with (readable) UTF8 characters?

Tags: c, utf-8, c++builder

I read a file that has utf8 characters like this:

```
FILE *FileIN,*FileOUT;
FileIN=fopen("filename","r");
char string[600];
WideChar C[600],S[100];
fgets(string,600,FileIN);
wcscpy(C,UTF8Decode(string).c_bstr()); // widechar copy
```

And it reads it perfectly (this is shown in the Editbox when running the program):

```
Edit1->Text=C;

Result ===> "3021";"亜";"7";"ア アシア つ.ぐ T1 や つぎ つぐ"
```

The thing is that when I want to write this on a file:

```
FileOUT=fopen("txt.txt","w");    
fwrite(Edit8->Text.c_str(),strlen(Edit8->Text.c_str()),1,FileOUT);

Result ===> "3021";"?";"7";"? ??? ?.? T1 ? ?? ??"
```

The question is, how do I write the result (the one i can see in the program running) in a file?

I use C language on CodeGear C++Builder

**Resolved**
thanks to Christoph and nobugz for the help

I changed this line

```
fwrite(Edit8->Text.c_str(),strlen(Edit8->Text.c_str()),1,FileOUT);
```

to this one and it worked. Thanks

```
fwrite(UTF8Encode(Edit8->Text).c_str(),UTF8Encode(Edit8->Text).Length(),1,FileOUT);
```

Comment: If some answers helped you, it would be nice if you voted them up and accepted some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the framework, but if you use `UTF8Decode()` after reading the file, shouldn't you use `UTF8Encode()` before writing?